# Migrate Firebird to Oracle

Tags: oracle, migration, firebird

I have about more than 250 Firebird local databases and several server databases. The way they are connected is such:

A block of almost 50 local databases, 1 on each PC, connect to 1 server database. This repeats for other blocks of almost 50 local databases for other server databases.

I would like to unite all the local databases with the server databases and migrate all this to Oracle.

What way do you recommend I do it? Are there solutions that will help me do it quickly and easily?

Edit:

Firebird version 2.5
Oracle 12.2 (Edited, we do have an 12.2 Oracle license)

Local databases have different data but equal schemes.
Server databases have different data but equal schemes.

The data should be migrated last and should be done quickly (within a day).

Comment: Have you tried SQL*Developer's Migration Workbench?  You'll need a JDBC driver to "other database".